# Jquery função click em links dinâmicos PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando criar um script para quando a pessoa clicar em Curtir ela vai curtir o post, e quando clicar em Descurtir, vai descurtir o post, óbvio, consegui fazer isso com sucesso, porém tive que fazer isso colocando o script jquery no PHP, fazendo com que a cada resultado, um novo script fosse criado, isso ficaria muito grande. Queria deixar somente 1 código, como eu faço pra pegar os IDS ali no caso dos resultados dinâmicos?

Vou explicar resumidamente, por que ficou meio confuso, quero ao em vez de ter que colocar esse javascript no select dinâmico, colocar apenas 1 código pra todos.

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // like and unlike click
    $("#like<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>, #unlike<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>").click(function(){

         var iconCarregando = $('<img src="loading.gif" width="70"> arregando. Por favor aguarde...');

                $('#statuslike<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>').html(iconCarregando);

            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'acoes.php?like=1&id=<?php echo $row['idd']; ?>',
        success: function(data){
      $(iconCarregando).remove();
    } });
    });
});
```

HTML

(o código está pela metade, por que não consigo botar o código completo)

```
a href="javascript:void(0);" id="like'.$msg_id.'" title="Like" rel="Like"><i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o margin-r-5"></i> Aplaudir
```

Comment: Precisamos ter noção do que você já fez e como está fazendo, para poder ajudar.

Comment: Mas eu já botei ali o.O

Comment: O jeito que eu fiz, e como eu queria que fosse, eu não sei fazer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa chamar o evento do clique pelo ID do botão. Você pode dar uma classe comum a todos (ex. `curtir`) e capturar todos os cliques ali. Depois de capturado você usa `$(this)` pra identificar qual botão foi clicado. Se não tiver a informação do ID em outro atributo, basta quebrar o ID pela parte conhecida. Ex.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // like and unlike click
    $(".curtir").click(function(){ // captura todos os cliques de curtir

         var iconCarregando = $('<img src="loading.gif" width="70"> arregando. Por favor aguarde...');

        var ID = $(this).attr('id').split('like')[1]; // pega o ID e retira a parte "like"

                $('#statuslike'+ID).html(iconCarregando);

            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'acoes.php?like=1&id='+ID,
        success: function(data){
      $(iconCarregando).remove();
    } });
    });
});
```

Comment: eu fiz como você falou e coloquei isso no html <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="curtir'.$msg_id.'" id="like'.$msg_id.'" title="Like" rel="Like"><i class="fa fa-hand-peace-o margin-r-5"></i> Curtir</a> mas não acontece nada ao clicar

Comment: usa só `class="curtir"` não precisa do msg_id ali

Comment: Amigo não da mesmo assim :\ já tentei ver o console e não aparece nenhum erro, o que pode ser?

Comment: será que é pq ele não ta conseguindo pegar o id? é oq eu acho pq como ele sabe qual é o id??

Comment: tinha um errinho ali, você precisa do índice [1], nao [0]. Alterei.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo, obrigado de coração

Answer (score 0):

Se o elemento foi criado dinamicamente utilize `on` do jQuery no elemento BODY ao invés de click direto e é claro insira este id no elemento que contém a classe clicável ex:

```
<div>
   <span id="id-do-botao-curtir" class="classe_clicavel">curtir</span>
</div>

$(body).on('click', '.classe_clicavel', function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // ex de teste ou sua lógica
    alert(id);
});
```